# Data merge without Object ID in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose.

Just like 'Mysql Join',
I want to get the data that merge the parents and children collection below.

**Parent**

```js
[
    {
        type: "A",
        results: [
            {
                "id": 111111
            },
            {
                "id": 222222
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        type: "B",
        results: [
            {
                "id": 333333
            },
            {
                "id": 444444
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Child**

```js
[
    {
        dataId: 111111,
        results: [
            { "status": { key: "value" } }
        ]
    },
    {
        dataId: 222222,
        results: [
            { "status": { key: "value" } }
        ]
    },
    {
        dataId: 333333,
        results: [
            { "status": { key: "value" } }
        ]
    },
    {
        dataId: 444444,
        results: [
            { "status": { key: "value" } }
        ]
    },
]
```

Because ObjectId cannot be inserted,
it seems that it cannot be processed using the population method.
I want to merge the two data like Join in MySQL.
like below

Parent.find()

```js
[
    {
        type: "A",
        results: [
            {
                "id": 111111,
                results: [
                    { "status": { key: "value" } }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 222222,
                results: [
                    { "status": { key: "value" } }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        type: "B",
        results: [
            {
                "id": 333333,
                results: [
                    { "status": { key: "value" } }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 444444,
                results: [
                    { "status": { key: "value" } }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query:

- `$unwind` to get every result from the array to merge with the Child `dataid`.
- `$lookup` which is the "join" in mongodb. Here query is mergin field `id` into `results` from the Parent with `dataId` from the Child.
- `$unwind` again because `$lookup` creates an array.
- `$group` to group the values according the id.
- `$project` (this stage is optional) to not shown fields you don't want.

```
yourParentModel.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$results"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Child",
      "localField": "results.id",
      "foreignField": "dataId",
      "as": "child_results"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$child_results"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "type": {
        "$first": "$type"
      },
      results: {
        "$push": "$child_results"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "results._id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RMvWTl6Sd48)

Answer (score 0):

you could do this from javascript directly

first you get the parent from mongoDB
( use mongoose find method)

```
let parents = [
  {
    type: "A",
    results: [
      {
        id: 111111,
      },
      {
        id: 222222,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    type: "B",
    results: [
      {
        id: 333333,
      },
      {
        id: 444444,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

then you get the child from the database

```
let children = [
  {
    dataId: 111111,
    results: [{ status: { key: "value" } }],
  },
  {
    dataId: 222222,
    results: [{ status: { key: "value" } }],
  },
  {
    dataId: 333333,
    results: [{ status: { key: "value" } }],
  },
  {
    dataId: 444444,
    results: [{ status: { key: "value" } }],
  },
];
```

and the treatement to merge the parents with the children will be something like this

```
for (let parent of parents) {
  for (let objectId of parent.results) {
    for (let child of children) {
      if (child.dataId === objectId.id) {
        objectId.results = child.results;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand that this is more efficient in dbms than in server-side code. I want to get it from dbms at once because I have a lot of data.

Comment: @sepw hmm, i am not a mongodb expert, but i guess that if there was a mongoose method to do that, it would the same complexity of server side code, one more thing, if you dont have a problem with losing more space, you could change the parent model in mongodb so that every parent contains the whole child instead of just its id and that would improve query execution time.